# mRemote stops opening my connections file :(

Tags: windows-7, mremote

I am using mRemote, and storing my connections file on a network drive (T:\foo...)
This morning, mRemote just started showing zero connections.
I tried to restart it, copy the connections file to another name and reopening, and nothing - it still shows zero connections.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The sad answer is that mRemote corrupted the connections file. The beginning of it looks find, but when I scroll to the end I find the XML file just is cut off somewhere. I'll go search for a backup :(